SpringBoot 3.3.1 native gets error: `ValueCodeGenerationException: Failed to generate code for AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext`
I added the graalvm.buildtools plugin:
<profile>
    <id>native</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skipNativeTests>true</skipNativeTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>

And then when I run mvn clean package -Pnative I get:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.aot.generate.ValueCodeGenerationException: Failed to generate code for 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5cdd09b1, started on Tue Jul 16 08:39:11 CEST 2024' with type class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.ValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(ValueCodeGenerator.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.generateValue(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.addPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanDefinitionPropertiesCodeGenerator.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.DefaultBeanRegistrationCodeFragments.generateSetBeanDefinitionPropertiesCode(DefaultBeanRegistrationCodeFragments.java:182)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationCodeGenerator.generateCode(BeanRegistrationCodeGenerator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.lambda$generateBeanDefinitionMethod$3(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:176)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.generateBeanDefinitionMethod(BeanDefinitionMethodGenerator.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod$2(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:90)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.generateRegisterBeanDefinitionsMethod(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.lambda$applyTo$1(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:73)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethod.<init>(GeneratedMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.GeneratedMethods.add(GeneratedMethods.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.applyTo(BeanRegistrationsAotContribution.java:72)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.applyTo(BeanFactoryInitializationAotContributions.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.lambda$processAheadOfTime$0(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.withCglibClassHandler(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:67)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ApplicationContextAotGenerator.processAheadOfTime(ApplicationContextAotGenerator.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.performAotProcessing(ContextAotProcessor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)
Caused by: org.springframework.aot.generate.UnsupportedTypeValueCodeGenerationException: Code generation does not support org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.aot.generate.ValueCodeGenerator.generateCode(ValueCodeGenerator.java:113)
        ... 28 more

Used:

SpringBoot: 3.3.1
Maven: 3.9.1
Java: graalvm-jdk-17.0.11+7.1

Does anyone know what causes the exception?

Please add your full pom.xml.

Are you trying to inject an instance of AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext somewhere? That's not supported with AOT. After the AOT processing, the application context won't be an annotation config context so such injection isn't supported.
